# Rails 4 - Devise - Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I am in hell trying to get rails 4 setup to work with devise (i have accepted defeat with omniauth).

I created an entirely new app & deployed it in heroku.

When I fill out the new registration form, I get an error message from heroku referring me to the logs. When I go to the logs, I get this. I don't understand any of it. Can anyone see the problem in this log?

```
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083702+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:58:in `valid?'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083698+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083706+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083699+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083707+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083716+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `save'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083709+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083716+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:19:in `create'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083710+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083708+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083709+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083703+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:37:in `save'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083714+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block in save'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083718+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083717+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083718+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083715+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:301:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083720+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083719+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083719+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083741+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083721+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083721+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083720+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083743+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083742+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083744+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083748+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083745+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083744+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083746+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083747+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083750+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083749+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083751+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083747+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083751+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083748+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083753+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083753+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083750+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083750+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083756+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083749+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083757+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083752+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083759+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083759+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083754+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083761+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083761+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083752+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083752+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083761+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083763+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083764+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083757+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083760+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083765+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083763+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083765+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083758+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083758+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083771+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083767+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083767+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083763+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083774+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083760+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083772+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083770+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083764+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083772+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083766+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083770+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083781+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083776+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083779+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083780+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083782+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083767+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083782+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083776+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083771+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083779+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083778+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083780+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083772+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083764+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083766+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083774+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083782+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.083781+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2015-12-08T22:14:04.090508+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=www.[x].com request_id=f4d0da9a-992c-48d0-856b-da92dbb9b2d0 fwd="49.195.28.229" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=105ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-12-08T22:14:04.472576+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.[x].com request_id=5d1718fd-14c9-4a4a-96f2-7891dc07a033 fwd="49.195.28.229" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=228
```

My set up has:

user.rb

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,
         :zxcvbnable, :confirmable, :lockable
```

routes

```
 devise_for :users, #class_name: 'FormUser',
             :controllers => {
                :registrations => "users/registrations",
                # :omniauth_callbacks => "users/authentications"
                # :omniauth_callbacks => 'users/omniauth_callbacks',
           }
```

view - nav

```
            <%= link_to("I'm new", new_user_registration_path) %>
            <span style= "padding-left: 10px">
              <%= link_to("Sign in", new_user_session_path) %>
```

users/regisrations controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController 

  private
    def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password )
    end


end
```

Following the suggestion below, I took off zxcvbnable from the user.rb and removed the check from devise.rb in the config folder.

There are validation checks in my user.rb for the presence of first and last name (and nothing else).

My new user form has:

```
<div class="form-inputs">
                            <%= f.input :first_name,  autofocus: true %>
                            <%= f.input :last_name %>
                            <%= f.input :email, placeholder: "Please use your work or university address" %>
                            <%= f.input :password, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @validatable), 
                                        :input_html => { class: 'estimate-password'} %>

                          </div>
```

When I restart the server and try again, I keep getting error notifications on the new user registration form saying first name and last name can't be blank. I keep typing them in and the process repeats.

THIS IS DRIVING ME CRAZY.

Comment: It looks to me as if some validation is failing when you are creating a user. (The valid? in the first line). Did you try it without  zxcvbnable?

Comment: Hi Johannes. I tried removing it. Now getting form errors with first name /last name can't be blank

Comment: http://jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html might help you. I don't have the time to check, but it seems like you missed something.. Don't worry, this error is progress ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Log is inconclusive; there are several things I would do to make sure it's okay:

> 1. Make sure you've migrated your database
> 2. Use the [`Devise sanitizers`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) for params

I personally think you're not passing the params properly, and are getting a failed validation as a result. This may be compounded by your database not being migrated, thus the `User` model not even having the attributes to begin with.

I'd do the following:

---

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

If you've already created the [`Devise` migration](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started), this will migrate all the changes to your production db.

If you haven't, you'll have to create it with `rails g devise:install`, which will create the files locally. You'll need to make sure you add them to your `git` repo, and push them to your server:

```
git add .
git commit -a -m "Devise Migration"
git push heroku master
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

This will make sure you have the appropriate attributes in your db (remember to add `first_name` and `last_name` if you haven't got them already).

-

Once you're sure you have all the relevant attributes in your db, you need to get your strong params sorted out.

Devise uses the `params sanitizer` to give you the ability to add extra parameters. This is contrary to using the standard `strong params` method, which although will work, is not recommended.

So I would do the following:

```
#app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, only: :create
   protected

   def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:first_name, :last_name]
   end
end
```